# Azure AD infinite login loop with Angular 9

Tags: angular, azure-active-directory

We have an Angular 9 SPA that uses an ADAL wrapper (https://github.com/Macadoshis/adal-angular8) for the Azure AD integration.  After publishing the application to our prod slot in Azure, we get an infinite redirect to the Azure AD login page and back to the main page of the application.  Eventually it comes up with "we couldn't log you in" and stops.

The same build, also authenticating against Azure AD (with different app registrations) works both in our Dev and Staging slot environments.

We suspect a configuration / redirect URL issue, but don't know how to isolate this problem yet.  Does anyone have any experience with solving this problem?

Answer (score 1):

```
app.config(['$locationProvider', function($locationProvider) {
    $locationProvider.html5Mode(true).hashPrefix('!');
}]);
```

Without the hashPrefix set, the AAD login will loop indefinitely as the callback URL from AAD (in the form of, {yourBaseUrl}/#{AADTokenAndState}) will be rewritten to remove the '#' causing the token parsing to fail and login sequence to occur again.

Please refer to this [document](https://github.com/AzureAD/azure-activedirectory-library-for-js/wiki/ADAL-angularjs).

> This library, ADAL for JavaScript, will no longer receive new feature
> improvements. Instead, use the new library MSAL.js.
>
> If you are starting a new project, you can get started with the
> MSAL.js docs for details about the scenarios, usage, and relevant
> concepts. If your application is using the previous ADAL JavaScript
> library, you can follow this migration guide to update to MSAL.js.
> Existing applications relying on ADAL JavaScript will continue to
> work.

Comment: Thanks for this pointer.   We do appear to have a hash in our callback URL, e.g the below fiddler log shows.:

`https://portal.xxxxxxxxxx.co.nz/#id_token=eyJ0eXAiOiJKV1QiLCJhbGciOiJSUzI1NiIsIng1dCI6IlNzWnNCTmhaY0YzUTlTNHRycFFCVEJ5TlJSSSIsImtpZCI6IlNzWnNCTmhaY0YzUTlTNHRycFFCVEJ5TlJSSSJ9.eyJhdWQik.....&amp;session_state=01c527fe-6de7-4efa-b176-0bda6a5399e1`

Please note we are running Angular 9 - the example you are linking is AngularJS - quite a bit older.  MSAL is definitely in our pipeline.

Comment: We also see this error in our API:  Bearer error="invalid_token", error_description="The audience 'fe17aee2-91d9-42ad-a590-e76a7e96394b' is invalid"

Comment: The error occurs because the audience present in the access token is not the same as the one that you are having . Please cross-check the audience your using.

Comment: Yes, this is correct.  We found the issue - was caused by slot mismatch between client application and our API - the slots somehow got mixed up and we have a client staging build that was sending the wrong client ID in the token.  As soon as we got the correct token the issue resolved.

Comment: Thank you for the Update